# Rails file upload with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have been uploading file with rails with rest-client, but when i change that into ajax,
 gives some server error.

FORM code

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'person',:action => 'create'},:multipart => true) do
%>  
<%= file_field_tag 'upload', :class => 'upload_name' %>
<%= submit_tag "Upload",  :class => "photo_up btn btn-success" %>   
<%end%>
```

AJAX code

```
$(function(){
$(".photo_up").click(function(){

var filename = $(".upload_name").val();

 $.ajax({
         url: '/create', //your server side script
         data: { upload: filename}, //our data
         type: 'POST',
         success: function (response) {                        
         }

     });
return false;
});
});
```

CONTROLLER code

```
file_param = params[:upload]
puts "name os #{file_param}"
show_url = "............."
resource = RestClient::Resource.new show_url, :user => "admin",:password => "admin"
response = resource.post  :file => file_param, :multipart => true
```

Here when i run this code, got the serve error 
**RestClient::InternalServerError (500 Internal Server Error):**, and i know that the server shows the null pointer, in the controller it gives the error in this line **response = resource.post  :file => file_param, :multipart => true**. But its run when in the normal form without ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy and universal way to send multipart forms via ajax

Look into jQuery ajaxForm plugin.
This makes this thing easy.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/